# I have a function but after a reload the function doesn't work, How can I keep the function activated?

Tags: javascript, php, function, reload

I want to show the attributes in the title, for this I use the function you can see here. But after I reload the page, the attributes are not in the title. So how can I keep the function activated even after a reload?
(I'am kinda new to this)

```
 <?php
    // Defining product Attributes term names to be displayed on variable product title
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'filter_available_variation_attributes', 10, 3 );
    function filter_available_variation_attributes( $data, $product, $variation ){
        // Here define the product attribute(s) slug(s) which values will be added to the product title
        // Or replace the array with 'all' string to display all attribute values
        $attribute_names = array('Custom', 'Color');
    
        foreach( $data['attributes'] as $attribute => $value ) {
            $attribute      = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attribute);
            $attribute_name = wc_attribute_label($attribute, $variation);
    
            if ( ( is_array($attribute_names) && in_array($attribute_name, $attribute_names) ) || $attribute_names === 'all' ) {
                $value = taxonomy_exists($attribute) ? get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $attribute )->name : $value;
    
                $data['for_title'][$attribute_name] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
    
    // Display to variable product title, defined product Attributes term names
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form', 'add_variation_attribute_on_product_title' );
    function add_variation_attribute_on_product_title(){
        // Here define the separator string
        $separator = ' - ';
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            var name = '<?php global $product; echo $product->get_name(); ?>';
    
            $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function(event, data) {
                var text = '';
    
                $.each( data.for_title, function( key, value ) {
                    text += '<?php echo $separator; ?>' + value;
                });
    
                $('.product_title').text( name + text );
    
            }).on('hide_variation', function(event, data) {
                $('.product_title').text( name );
            });
        })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If you want to save data between reloads, use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Do you know a website or something else where I can find more information about this? 
Because I don't really know how I can add that in the code.

Comment: Okey thanks I will look into it

Comment: and easy solution its just put some string inside a none display div then when DOM are loaded you just check the none display and activate the function.

Comment: I'am very new to this and I kinda understand your questions but I have no clue how to add that to the code. I have visited 300 websites to try to keep the function activated after a refresh but still nothing.